# adding a link to justified text

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

I was wondering if I could seamlessly add a link to justified text. I would like for the link to be justified within the text and keep its position. The desired output will look like one paragraph. I have tried two methods thus far.

**one**

The html :

```
<div>
  <p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunkof  text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
  <a href="#"> This is a link.</a>
  <p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
</div>
```

css :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
}
p, a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline;
}
```

the result is :

a chunk of text, a line break, the link, a line break, then the last chunk of text.

I would like to seamlessly add the link to the justified text. is that possible with just css?

**two**

When I put the link in the paragraph, it seems to randomly insert it near the actual location between text nodes. Could be treating the link as one word?

html :

```
<div>
    <p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunkof  text. link-><a href="#"> This is a link.</a><-link This is a chunk of text.</p>
    <p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
</div>
```

In the output the link does not line up with "link-> <-link"

I suppose if this is the better of the two options I would just like to know why the link won't line up with it's position alliterative to the text nodes. "link->", "<-link"

Comment: have you tried to put the link in the paragraph?

Comment: When I put the link in the paragraph, it seems to randomly insert it near the actual location between text nodes. Could be treating the link as one word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working as it should be for `inline` but in your `css` you have

```
div {
    width: 200px;
}
```

and all other elements are inside that `div` so it's your div that causing the line breaks, if you set the width of your `div` more then it'll be displayed in one line, which is (inline) working right now.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3reY5/).

**Update:** [Also you may try this](http://jsfiddle.net/3reY5/3/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
div {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
}
p{
    display: inline;
}
a{
  float:left;
}
```

​

Comment: the width was set low to test the justification.

Comment: @Chris, your `inline` is working but `div's` width is set to `200px` and in my example I've set it to `1000px` so the line brakes not happening.

Comment: Thank you for your response but, I want the anchor to justify into the text so it looks like one paragraph in the output. I set the width to 200px intentionally. to force word-wrap to occur within the p elements. I am getting a feeling like this is a limitation of css.

Comment: @Chris, then you should have mentioned it clearly, I just misunderstood. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/3reY5/1/).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about not asking my question with specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Like Heera mentioned.

```
div {
width: 200px;
}
```

Is causing the line breaks as that is probably not wide enough. You will need to increase that.

If you are wanting the link to line up with the text than do it like this.

```
<div>
<p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunkof  text. This is a chunk of text.
<a href="#"> This is a link.</a></p>
<p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
</div>
```

Other wise you would have to add a class for both the link and paragraph tag to make them float and display inline. It would be simpler to just do the above method.

If you rather do it the other way than this should work

```
<div>
<p class="firstP">This is a chunk of text. This is a chunkof  text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
<a href="#"> This is a link.</a> 
<div class="breaker"></div>
<p>This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text. This is a chunk of text.</p>
</div>

p.firstP { 
float: left; 
display: inline-block; 
}

div a  { 
float: left; 
display: inline-block; 
} 

.breaker {
clear: both;
}
```